# $H^{\frac{3}{2}-\epsilon}\left(\Omega\right)\hookrightarrow\hookrightarrow H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$ for $\epsilon\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I need know if $H^{\frac{3}{2}-\epsilon}\left(\Omega\right)\hookrightarrow\hookrightarrow H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$, for $\epsilon\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\Omega$ a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with $n=2,3$.
Well, I don't know a good book for theorems of compact embeddings between Fractional Sobolev Spaces ($W^{s_{1},p}\left(\Omega\right)\hookrightarrow\hookrightarrow W^{s_{2},q}\left(\Omega\right)$ ?). Any reference?

Comment: I suppose you can start with https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich–Kondrachov_theorem .

Comment: In the book of Demengel (Theorem 4.54) you can find the result $H^{1/2-\epsilon} \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2$, then you just have to rise the order by $1$.

Comment: Thanks you @Fritz ! Long life to you